# How to get and pass customer information in Stripe?

Tags: node.js, swift, heroku, stripe-payments

Having trouble getting a customer_id for my stripe transactions. 
[image]

1) How do we get a customer_id from Stripe? I'm assuming it starts once I register the user (getting their name and email). However, Stripe documentation is unclear. Does anyone have a clear code on this?

2) How/where do we put it back into the system?

Backend: Node. js. Heroku

Comment: Your question is little bit unclear. Are you trying to retrieve the customer_id from Balance Transaction or do you have a problem storing the customer_id when the customer is created? Please let me know.

Comment: @MadhuJayarama Both. Trying to generate a customer_id from my app once a.user signs up (without the dashboard). And then passing it when the card is charged. Is this possible? Most documentation shows us how to do it in the dashboard, but that doesn't make much sense... since it's an app?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the customer with the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create), the API response will contain the ID of the customer. Here's an example in Node.js.

```
const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
  description: 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs)',
});

// This is the customer ID that is of the form "cus_xxx"
console.log(customer.id);
```

If you create the Customer in the Stripe Dashboard, the ID of the Customer is in the URL when viewing the detail page. Additionally, it's in the top right pane of the Customer detail view.

[image: Stripe Customer ID in Dashboard]

This Customer ID can then be used when creating PaymentIntents, Subscriptions and other objects that expect a customer ID. A full list of parameters is available for each API in the [full API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a customer with the help of [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create).

```
const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    description: 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs)',
});

const customerId = customer.id;
```

Then you can store this stripe customerId in your database for the particular customer so that you can use this customerId later for Balance Transaction or for creating Payment Intents.

**Please note** : [Retrieve Balance Transaction API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/retrieve) will not directly give the customerId of the customer who has made the transaction.

For that, you need to retrieve the source(chargeId) from the balance transaction.

```
const transactionId = 'txn_1CzRLEEHiz05HoqrMuNqqHD1'; // Replace this with Balance transaction id which you have to retrieve.
stripe.balanceTransactions.retrieve(
    transactionId,
    function(err, balanceTransaction) {
       const chargeId = balanceTransaction.source;
    }
);
```

Once you get the chargeId for that particular Balance Transaction, you can use this chargeId in [Retrieve a Charge API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/retrieve), to know the customerId.

```
stripe.charges.retrieve(
    chargeId,
    function(err, charge) {
       // asynchronously called
       const customerId = charge.customer;
    }
);
```

So now, you have a customerId of the customer who has made that Transaction.
I hope this helps.